# Sequence $X$ in ordered field converges $\Rightarrow$ all subsequences of $X$ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have read the below statement from the textbook:

### "Sequence $X$ in ordered field converges $\Rightarrow$ all subsequences of $X$ converge"

Question:

How could it be true?

If a sequence $X$ converges to $a\in F$, it means that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $\forall i \in\Bbb N\ge N, |X_n-a| \lt \varepsilon$

Then, from $X$, if we take only subsequences which are less than $N$, it does not guarantee that this sequence actually converges.

Comment: Taking finite subsequences (are these considered subsequences?) doesn't guarantee convergence.  If they're infinite it should.  Do you see why?

Comment: In every subsequence, the indices will eventually exceed $N$, so the points will be in $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$.

Comment: great comment. Finite subsequences are not subsequences? if it's infinite, I understand it always converges to same point to the orginal one.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue of definition of terms. Finitely long subsequences are not considered "subsequences" for the purposes of this statement. A reasonable account of the matter should have a definition of "subsequence" that explains that before stating a proposition of this kind. The concept of "convergence" doesn't make sense for finitely long sequences.